# HighStock - Add series dynamically to navigator

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using the AddSeries method for my HighStock chart, and I would like the added series to also show up in the navigator.

In the documentation for the HighStock AddSeries method it is described that this is not possible:
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Chart.addSeries

> In a StockChart with the navigator enabled, the base series can't be added dynamically

I would like to ask if there is any workaround for this? Is this a feature that is coming soon, or is there a good reason for why the series aren't added to the navigator?

The only workaround I can think of is to destroy the entire chart and create a new one with both the old and new series. This seems kinda hacky, and I would prefer to just use the AddSeries method, since I think it makes more sense.

Thanks :)

**EDIT**

I found out that (with help from Grzegorz Blachliński) it works if the type is **not** `line` (which is the default). I didn't provide the type property, which was why it wasn't working. Still don't get why `line` makes it break though.

```
//Solution:
chart.addSeries({
    name: 'name',
    type: 'area',
    color: 'red',
    yAxis: 'nameOfYAxis',
    data: data,
    showInNavigator: true
});
```

Thanks a lot Grzegorz Blachliński :)

Comment: You should be able to add you series with showInNavigator option: http://jsfiddle.net/g51L5mpL/ If this example will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzBlachliński - with your example I figured it out and I have edited the question with the solution. Please post your comment as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your message! I am not sure if line series is breaking navigator: http://jsfiddle.net/g51L5mpL/1/ Also adding series with default type: http://jsfiddle.net/g51L5mpL/2/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński You're right! It was my data-series that got me confused. The values were too far from eachother so I couldn't see the newly added serie in the navigator. I also got confused when I read the documentation that said: "In a StockChart with the navigator enabled, the base series can't be added dynamically". 
Anyway - Thanks a bunch, you saved my day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in your case you should be able to use showInNavigator option for adding series both to your chart and to your navigator. You can find more information about showInNavigator in Highcharts API:

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.showInNavigator

```
chart.addSeries({
  data: data2,
  showInNavigator: true,
});
```

Live example of adding series to navigator:
http://jsfiddle.net/g51L5mpL/4/